# ¿Qué hacer si una respuesta aceptada no incluye referencias de origen al código que muestra?

Tags: soporte, respuesta, ediciones, código-de-conducta

Estoy revisando preguntas acerca de carga de archivos. En una de ellas encontré una respuesta aceptada, valiosa, que usa a modo de código de ejemplo, el código que se muestra en el primer ejemplo de una página del manual oficial de PHP. Y por mala lectura creí que no incluía las referencias al origen.

Pensé editarla e incluir la referencia y no lo hice porque no me parece bien aparecer como coautor de la respuesta.

Si no me hubiese equivocado la referencia haría falta porque SOes mantiene el texto publicado, ¿Cuál sería el camino correcto? allí y en casos similares.

Comment: Según veo en la respuesta que enlazas, si que tiene el enlace al código y la documentación original (fíjate justo antes del código).

Comment: Si, pero el problema es cual es mi paso siguiente, porque el aporte fue valioso

Comment: No termino de entender tu comentario. Tu pregunta es que hacer si la respuesta no incluye la referencia, y en este caso si lo hace. A que te refieres con paso siguiente?

Comment: Jajaja. Es que o leí mal o no incluye los créditos al origen del código, y el paso siguiente sería incluirlos pero, como comentario de la comunidad, no como acción de edición mía

Comment: Como te digo en mi primer comentario, si que lo hace. Dice exactamente lo siguiente: _Aquí te dejo la documentación de como generar el hash http://php.net/manual/es/function.sha1-file.php_

Comment: Entonces me retracto!! jajaja, no lo ví

Comment: Pero mi pregunta sigue siendo válida, quitando el ejemplo

Comment: De todas maneras, en el caso de que no fuera así, yo personalmente lo que haría sería primero añadir un comentario sugiriendo al autor que añadiera la referencia, y si tras un tiempo prudencial no contesta, directamente puedes editarlo tu.

Comment: @quevedo Cuando editas una pregunta o una respuesta no eres el "coautor", eres el editor, en ningún caso se te atribuirán los méritos del autor, únicamente te darán 2 puntos de rep por editarla. Ademas solo aparecerá el nombre del ultimo editor, por lo que si alguien hace mas cambios después tuyo ya no aparecerá tu nombre. Si crees que con tu edición la respuesta se vera mejor ,mas enriquecida y de mejor calidad , adelante, asi se mejora la calidad del sitio

Comment: En tu caso además no sería una edición automática ya que no tienes reputación suficiente, tendría que pasar por el proceso de aprobación, así que no tengas miedo de sugerir una edición si consideras que es necesaria.

Comment: Gracias. Además ya corregí mi barbaridad acá!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> no me parece bien aparecer como coautor de la respuesta.

Mi estimado, muy respetable lo que te parezca o no te parezca pero **por favor**, considera que la premisa básica de los sitios de Stack Exchange es la colaboración y por otro en estos espacios no se maneja el concepto de "coautor" de igual forma como ocurre en otros como lo sería el de una publicación académica o un libro, si me permites la expresión, "tradicionales".

Para más información consulta [¿Por qué puede la gente editar mis mensajes? ¿Cómo funciona el trabajo de edición?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/editing)

> encontré una respuesta aceptada, valiosa, que usa a modo de código de ejemplo, el código que se muestra en el primer ejemplo de una página del manual oficial de PHP. Y por mala lectura creí que no incluía las referencias al origen.

Aun y cuando las publicaciones en este sitio no son publicaciones tradicionales en el sentido de las publicaciones impresas, los conceptos de derechos de autor y plagio sigue siendo relevantes y al respecto tenemos una guía sobre [¿Cómo referenciar material escrito por otra persona?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/referencing).

Si encuentras una publicación, ya sea pregunta o respuesta en la que no se respetan los derechos de autor / se comete plagio, dependiendo de la intención original se debería reportar, comentar o editar.

Me parece que lo más apropiado sería presumir que las intenciones son las mejores, pero como podría haber incertidumbre ya sea de las intenciones o preferencias del autor, lo más apropiado podría ser dejar un comentario.

Cuando sea evidente la intención de plagiar por parte del OP, reporta la publicación y cuando sea evidente la fuente, edita para agregar esta.